# What the usage of "have sufficient in common" is?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

> We have suggested that restrictions on the pairings of pronouns with
> antecedents **have sufficient in common with those** on pairings of
> articles or attributive adjectives and head noun in [1] for us to
> treat them as a matter of agreement. Nevertheless, there are
> significant differences between the two types of agreement.

Because 'sufficient' is an adj, this usage(have + adj + PP ) really confuses me.

Comment: @ Mr. Wang Would this be helpful for you?            
"sufficient" 
in British English:
ADJECTIVE....(those interpretations you obviously know, but it also has a noun meaning) 
NOUN
"a sufficient quantity"
(Collins English Dictionary)

Comment: In English, the word sufficient can be both an adjective, and a noun. In the example it's a noun. The OED has this entry for the noun "A sufficent quantity or supply; sufficient means; enough". I can't share the link as it's behind a login, but [here's the screenshot](https://imgur.com/3wvSvNC).  So, you could paraphrase this as something like  "[They] have enough in common . . . for us to treat them as . . . "

Comment: "Have enough in common" is the more usual phrase, but "sufficient" is a synonym of "enough" here. (You should state your source - it's possible it's written by a non-native speaker but they may want to sound scientific or just be bored of typing "enough".)